# Cannot access Hyper-V machine via OpenVPN

Tags: networking, hyper-v, openvpn

We have an XP/SP3 Hyper-V machine running at Windows2012 Server.
There is no problem to connect that virtual machine via mstsc or ping it from within our LAN.
We have a branch in other city. They access our network using OpenVPN. They can ping both network adapters of the server, but not the virtual machine running on it.
**What's wrong in this combination?**

Note: A virtual switch is used, VLAN not enabled. A virtual adapter has just IPv4 enabled. Is there anything more to set? The machine at our branch which tries to ping/mstsc the Hyper-V machine is Windows8.

Comment: 1. do you have firewall utm? if yes did you configure a rule for that branch network in vpn inbound to access that server? 2. how did you configure the virtual swtich in hyper-v?

Comment: Today, the VM is switched off (this question is a bit old), so I can't provide the details requested. But I think if there was a problem in the firewall, the users couldn't ping that server via VPN. And if there was a problem in the Hyper-V virtual switch configuration, it couldn't work from within our LAN.